# League of Legends Health Bar UI Bug

Tags: league-of-legends

Ever since the last patch, I've had a problem with the health bars. I had PerbUI mod since like last year, and when the new UI was put in everything but the health bars were changed for me. I eventually forgot I even had the mod. Now in the game the UI looks like it does in these pictures. I have to turn colorblind mode on to make it look somewhat normal. I already tried to repair the install for LoL from the launcher and it didn't do anything as far as I can see. I would be fine playing with colorblind mode on, but I can't see how much health someone has without clicking on them.

Colorblind mode Off
[image: Colorblind Mode Off]

Colorblind mode On
[image: Colorblind mode On]

Comment: Does the happen every game for you? I had this bug happen once but simply restarting LoL fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I restarted LoL and my computer and it didn't do anything

Comment: The [Support Site](http://support.leagueoflegends.com) or the [Support Forums](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f=15) are where you should take issues like this.  That said, just reinstall, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If the mod is still active, that is most likely causing the issue. They did a few UI improvements in this last patch which may have caused the mod to go out of date and isn't compatible with this new version.

Waiting for that mod to be updated to support the new UI updates, or disabling the mod seem to be your only options since you mention you tried repairing the client already.